# GNU Screen: how to start a bash process and execute a command within it?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to set up a screenrc file that opens a few windows, and in one of them I'd like to start a shell and start vim within it (rather than starting vim directly). I've tried things along the lines of

```
screen -t vim -ln 1 bash -c "vim"
```

but that seems to open vim directly (if I quit vim, the window is killed, whereas I'd like to simply return to the shell in that window). How can I set this up correctly?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, care to explain the usefulness of this?

Comment: For one, I could use Ctrl-Z to suspend Vim for a moment, do something in the shell, then `fg` to bounce back into Vim. Another example, I have a Rails server running in one window. Occasionally I'd like to stop the server, do something in that window, then start the server up again. Both these scenarios require the window to have been initialized as a shell session.

Comment: To use a temporary shell in `vim`, issue `:!bash`. When you exit that shell, you'll be back in `vim`. Still, little to no point in `screen`. If you need an extra shell, just `Ctrl-A Ctrl-c`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this workaround:

```
screen -t vim bash -c "vim; bash"
```

Comment: That's no workaround. That's the correct solution. :-)